# Github merge process

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

I have merged from my main project to my other project many times on github. I did the same process again, but something went wrong, I had to revert. Then I tried to fix it by creating a merge again, but the changes are not detected. How can i solve this problem. I hope it's not too complicated a problem.

Comment: "revert" was probably the wrong way to fix the original problem - a revert creates an *extra* commit that reverses the *changes* made to the code, but it doesn't "undo" changes to the *history* used to decide what is "new" in a merge.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all local (i.e. not pushed or on remote), you could simply do `git reset --hard <sha1>` to reset to the state prior to the merge. `<sha1>` is the commit before the merge.

However, if you've already pushed the merge and you're trying to re-merge the same branch to fix the issue, you also need to perform a `git revert` on the revert commit that undid the merge.

Linus Torvalds, the creator of git, explains it well in [How to Revert a Faulty Merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt). He states:

> Reverting a regular commit just effectively undoes what that commit
> did, and is fairly straightforward. But reverting a merge commit also
> undoes the *data* that the commit changed, but it does absolutely
> nothing to the effects on *history* that the merge had.
>
> So the merge will still exist, and it will still be seen as joining
> the two branches together, and future merges will see that merge as
> the last shared state - and the revert that reverted the merge brought
> in will not affect that at all.
>
> So a "revert" undoes the data changes, but it's very much *not* an
> "undo" in the sense that it doesn't undo the effects of a commit on
> the repository history.
> In such a situation, you would want to first revert the previous revert [...].

I encourage you to read the full email/documentation as it's quite insightful.